# Rotate screen, return to same location

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have a textviewer with HTML text in it (let's say with 200 lines). TextViewer is in a ScrollView, and the activity has in manifest: android:configChanges="orientation" (to avoid restarting activity).

When I rotate screen - I get the text rotated but it does not show the same line, since each line can show more.

How do I rotate and show same beginning of line?